# How to combine JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables; products and response.

I need to grab quantity of response for current product.

For example product with id 106 has two responses and with id 105 one response.

Another products don't have responses.

My example of query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products P 
  LEFT 
  JOIN response R 
    ON R.product_id = P.id
```

It returns 14 arrays(I have only 13 products) so that one product which has two responses repeats two times.

I should create more accurate query which returns quantity of response for each product..

Comment: Please take a few minutes and edit your question to include sample data as a table in text.

Answer (score 1):

Group by all the columns you want to select from the `products` table

```
SELECT P.id, count(r.product_id) as response_count
FROM products P 
LEFT JOIN response R ON R.product_id = P.id
group by P.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return you records with two columns product_id and product_count.

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as product_count FROM products P LEFT JOIN response R ON R.product_id = P.id" GROUP BY product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what quantity of response is, there are two cases.

This has been answered previously as well ([MySQL LEFT JOIN with GROUP BY and WHERE IN (sub query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321182/mysql-left-join-with-group-by-and-where-in-sub-query))

**Counting the responses**

```
SELECT R.product_id, count(P.id) as NumberOfResponses 
FROM products P 
LEFT JOIN response R 
ON R.product_id = P.id
group by R.product_id
```

**Summing the response quantity**

```
SELECT R.product_id, sum(P.quantity_column) as TotalQuantityOfResponses FROM products P 
LEFT JOIN response R 
ON R.product_id = P.id
group by R.product_id
```